# Using Grails for Web Service Client Project

Tags: spring, grails, rest-client, webservices-client

I'm currently researching on Grails, if it would be a good choice to go with a Web Service client project. It is said Grails is highly beneficial for developing Admin Portals and Prototypes. However my concern is to use Grails for an Admin Portal where the Admin Portal is driven by the Rest-API calls. Therefore, I can consider that as a Web Service Client application. Hence, I won't be able get much use of Grails scaffolding feature to generate controllers or its related test cases. And also the Object Relational Mapping via Hibernate as well. But still I can get the views generated according to the domain objects that I'm defining. Considering the above concerns is Grails still reasonably beneficial than going with traditional Java/Spring and Spring RestTemplate approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a subjective question, but IMO yes, a Grails web application that is primarily a web service consumer is still a fine choice.  Groovy's remote API functionality is very productive and clean, and the view layer and controllers are high quality regardless of what the domain/service layer looks like.

In my current project one of our Grails apps is acting just like how you're describing, and it's been a success in terms of quality, performance, and productivity.